# How to redirect users after Meteor.loginWithFacebook in Meteor

Tags: facebook, meteor, facebook-login, iron-router

I have gotten the 3rd party Facebook login to work. I am now trying to figure out how to redirect my users to my "primaryLayout" template. Do I do this using iron:router or is there a better way?

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
Template.fbLogin.events({
    'click #facebook-login': function(event) {
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login didn't work!");
            }


        });
    },

    'click #logout': function(event) {
        Meteor.logout(function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Login has failed.");
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this.

```
Template.fbLogin.events({
    'click #facebook-login': function(event) {
        Meteor.loginWithFacebook({}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Facebook login didn't work!");
            }else{
            Router.go('/templateDesired') //or whatever Template you wanna go
              }


        });
    },

    'click #logout': function(event) {
        Meteor.logout(function(err){
            if (err) {
                throw new Meteor.Error("Login has failed.");
            }
        })
    }
})
```